# Word, phrase or idiom for an action taken for solely political advantage

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

Is there a word, phrase or idiom for an action taken for solely political advantage (although superficially this might be non-obvious)?

Example:

> What evidence is there that Lyndon Johnson's War on Poverty was more
>   than a [political action for his advantage, although superficially a
>   poverty reduction programme].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could consider using "political [***gimmick***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/gimmick)". "Gimmick" means:

> A trick or device intended to attract attention, publicity, or trade:
>   'it is not so much a programme to improve services as a gimmick to gain
>   votes'

[Oxford Online Dictionary]

> What evidence is there that Lyndon Johnson's War on Poverty was more
>   than a "political gimmick"?

Comment: Great word, *gimmick*. +1.

Answer (score 3):

In this context, **political maneuver** should work:

> maneuver: a clever or dishonest action that you do to get something that you want
>   *Mercer won the election thanks to the maneuver of his son-in-law.*

(Macmillan English Dictionary)

In your case you could say:

> What evidence is there that Lyndon Johnson's War on Poverty was more than a **political maneuver**?

Another possibility is "**political [ploy](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/ploy)**":

> Hillary Clinton Ad Calls House Inquiry a Political Ploy

([www.nytimes.com](http://www.nytimes.com/2015/10/06/us/politics/hillary-clinton-ad-calls-house-inquiry-a-political-ploy.html?_r=0))

Answer (score 2):

Consider **political opportunism**.

Opportunism ([MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/opportunism)):

> the art, policy, or practice of taking advantage of opportunities or circumstances often with little regard for principles or consequences

Cf. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Political_opportunism). In your example:

> What evidence is there that Lyndon Johnson's War on Poverty was more than mere political opportunism?

Answer (score 2):

I' use ***[politics](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/politics)***:

> - (used with a sing. or pl. verb) Intrigue or maneuvering within a political unit or a group in order to gain control or power: *Partisan politics is often an obstruction to good government. Office politics are often debilitating and counterproductive.*'

- What evidence is there that Lyndon Johnson's War on Poverty was more than partisan politics?

(AHD)

Answer (score 2):

Cunning political moves are often described as ["Machiavellian"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machiavellianism), especially if there is a significant component of deception, selfishness, and disregard for morality.

Answer (score 1):

Others have given good answers in the context of an individual acting for his own benefit.

When it concerns the motives of a nation state, the word **realpolitik** describes actions that are driven by narrow self-interest rather than wider idealistic motives. The definition of the word as per the [Merriam-Webster dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/realpolitik):

> **realpolitik**
>         noun, re·al·po·li·tik often capitalized \rā-ˈäl-ˌpō-li-ˌtēk\
>   : a system of politics based on a country's situation and its needs rather than on ideas about what is morally right and wrong
>
> Full Definition of REALPOLITIK
>
> :  politics based on practical and material factors rather than on theoretical or ethical objectives

Answer (score 1):

You may say:

> What evidence is there that Lyndon Johnson's War on Poverty was **more
>   than just empty rhetoric**?"

*"rhetoric" refers to*:

- *the art of making persuasive speeches*,
- *the art of influencing thethought and conduct of an audience*,
- *the undue use of exaggeration or display*.

Comment: The question specifically asks about political _actions_, not speech.

Comment: @ 200_success - I assumed that the OP's sentence compared Lyndon Johnson's claim for "War against poverty" to his effective political action.

Comment: I think "empty rhetoric" works very well in a sense that it is an empty promise. +1)

Answer (score 1):

How about the word "ingratiate" ?

It means to do or say something to gain favor and is often used in political contexts.

The candidate ingratiated his republican constituents by claiming to own a large arsenal of firearms.